# How combine 2 functions on submit?

Tags: javascript, html, function

as you can see, i have to functions first to check if all forms are not empty and the second function is to verify the captcher, when i combine them together both work at the same time, i want to first to verify the first function, when that function returns true then the other function starts,

here is the code that i used on form

```
<form  action="reg.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit=" Checking(this); return jcap();" >
```

As you can see both function execute at the same time

so i tried this

```
<form  action="reg.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit=" if(Checking(this) == true ){ return jcap();}" >
```

is bypass both

i also tried this

```
<form  action="reg.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit=" return(Checking(this) && jcap(this));" >
```

and it bypassed jcap function

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the actual question.

Comment: @ ABach i want to verify the form first then checks the captcha but when both are combined on one `onsubmit` both work together, i want to split them where verify first then captcha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like that `Checking()` doesn't have a valid return value. The script might have errored and block the processing. Update the function accordingly. E.g.

```
function Checking(form) {
    if (form is valid) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This way the third approach should work.

---

That said (and unrelated to the actual problem), I'd try to follow the JavaScript coding conventions (functions start with lowercase) and also give the functions a bit more sensible name, e.g. `checkCaptcha()` and `checkForm()`.

Comment: hey there, thank you, but a problem occurs when i user this function `function checkAll(form) {if(checkForm(form)== true){if(jcap(form) == true){return true;}}else{ return false;}}` if i used jcap in the begining everything works smooth but the send button wont work, if i keept it like this everything works smooth but when it reaches to verification nothing happenes

Comment: If the button doesn't work, then it means that the function didn't return `true`. I'd say, run a JS debugger to track the code execution step by step, e.g. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com). If you want more assistance, you'll really need to update your question to include a self contained and executabele example, with the *minimum* amount of needed code to reproduce the very same problem, so that we can copy'n'paste'n'run it.

Comment: hey there after trying for an hour on try to catch the error i found out that i missed entering `return false` at the end of `if statment` thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Combine both of them in a function:

```
function checkMyForm() {
  if(check_fields() == true) {
    if(check_captha() == true) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: hey there, i tried it but it bypass both this what i did

`function checkMyForm() {if(Checking() == true) {if(jcap() == true){return true;}}return false;}`
and on the form

`<form  action="reg.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit=" return(checkMyForm());" >`

Answer (score 0):

No your onsubmit syntax is wrong.

Try this

```
function checkForm() {
    if(Checking() && jcap())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

and your form:

```
<form action="reg.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
```